# How to get access token and expire time using Google account to login

Tags: android, google-oauth

I'm developing an app that use google's sign-in service to login and create new account for the first time, I already get display name, email, image via Person method, but I'm not sure which method can get access token and expire time, those two values are the key values creating a new account, please help if you know, thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, there is a GIDAuthentication method can get accessToken and accessTokenExpirationDate directly according to the iOS api reference, but what about android?

Comment: you can see this answer hope help for you
[Google access token expiration time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851157/oauth2-and-google-api-access-token-expiration-time) [OAuth2 and Google API: Access token expiration time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851157/oauth2-and-google-api-access-token-expiration-time)

Comment: @Sambhaji I'm have look into this answer, but it's a java web application solution not for android app, I think there is a method can get those values directly just like iOS.