# Using Google Drive as a storage provider from within a web app - how to grant perpetual access to a folder?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have a web application that allows users to draw pictures.

I'd like to enable users to configure Google Drive as a place to store their media by configuring Google Drive as their storage service during onboarding.

I see that authorization (that gives me `access_token`) currently has an expiration of `3600`s.  How can I allow the user to grant my app perpetual access to their google drive - ideally just a folder - so that they don't have to reauthenticate every time they use my web app (JS)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851157/oauth2-and-google-api-access-token-expiration-time

Comment: It might help to understand the workflow you are trying to achieve. As SO link provided in the comments above notes once the app is authorized it does not expire unless revoked. This is the case in a standard Oauth2 (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) workflow. Is that what you are doing?