# Get service account auth token without gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Is it possible to get an authorization bearer token for a Google Cloud service account without the use of `gcloud`?

That is, I would like to make an HTTP request (presumably signed in some way by my JSON key file) that would provide me the equivalent of

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

This request would be made on my own server, where I may not wish to install `gcloud` and where I do not have access to any internal server metadata that might provide this (e.g., as is the case with Compute Engine).

Is there some oauth endpoint that provides something like this?

Alternately, is there some way to generate long-lived tokens with `gcloud`?

I'm new to the Google Cloud ecosystem, so excuse my ignorance and terminology...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think that this is exactly what you are looking for:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount

Honestly I don't think that what you were trying to achieve was correct, running

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

you get a token that is not intended to do what you were looking for:

"This command is useful when you are developing code that would normally use a service account but need to run the code in a local development environment where it's easier to provide user credentials."

This should guide you a bit more in the implementation of this solution:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Thanks, I think that's exactly what I need! All of the examples/tutorials I was looking at for Cloud APIs just used the `gcloud` auth mechanism...

Comment: I am having similar problems @JacobBrown . Could you solve the issue and provide me some code? I am completely new to this and trying to connect a chrome extension to my google cloud ml model.  I should do a CURL request that looks like this: $
    curl -X POST \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://automl.googleapis.com/v1/projects/1243/locations/us-central1/models/TCN824464:predict \
  -d request.json

Comment: Be aware this only lasts for 1 hour.

Answer (score 4):

If your code runs on a GCE VM and  you don't mind using that VMs service-account, then There is no need for a library or an api. You can obtain an access token using curl:

```
curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" | jq -r .access_token
```

It is useful if you need it in a shell script.

Comment: This *is* a useful snippet. You need to provide a little context though - this will only work from a GCE VM and will use that VMs service-account. I suspect confusion about that is why this is getting downvoted.

I'd also note that you *are* using an API - the instance metadata API: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/accessing-instance-metadata

Comment: This was my first life saver of today. Here is my second life saver if you're using Cloud Build: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70146668/9022841

Answer (score 4):

Here's what it looks like in golang:

```
import(
    "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
    "google.golang.org/api/container/v1"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "google.golang.org/api/transport"
)
ctx := context.Background()
creds, err := transport.Creds(ctx, option.WithScopes(compute.CloudPlatformScope))
token, err := creds.TokenSource.Token()
```

Answer (score 2):

For your second question, “is there some way to generate long-lived tokens with gcloud?”, no there is not. However, you can use a refresh token to generate new access tokens.
Check the first answer for this question:

[OAuth2 and Google API: Access token expiration time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851157/oauth2-and-google-api-access-token-expiration-time)

And also, here’s an example of a python library that you can use as an authentication mechanism:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/oauth2/credentials.py

Comment: Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java#explicit-credential-loading

> Explicit Credential Loading
> To get Credentials from a Service Account JSON key use GoogleCredentials.fromStream(InputStream) or GoogleCredentials.fromStream(InputStream, HttpTransportFactory). Note that the credentials must be refreshed before the access token is available.

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/credentials.json"));
credentials.refreshIfExpired();
AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();
// OR
AccessToken token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
```