# How to access Dialogflow V2 API from a webpage?

Tags: nlp, chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have a webpage where I want to use dialogflow chatbot. This is a custom chat window, so I don't want to use one click integration. I am able to access the chat agent **V1 API** using javascript/ajax (by passing **client access token** in the request header).

But I don't know how to do it in **V2 API**. The dialogflow documentation is not clear to me(I have setup Authentication by referring [this](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup#using_the_key) link. I don't know how to proceed further). I'm not familiar with Google cloud either. So a working sample or a step by step how to access the API guideline will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This question seems to already have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059976/get-service-account-auth-token-without-gcloud

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545943/dialogflow-easy-way-for-authorization/51941682#51941682 ... Try this instead of require.. use import... Working for Angular 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dialogflow easy way for authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545943/dialogflow-easy-way-for-authorization)

Comment: You must use a web server side to access Dialogflow V2 API. Read this: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-api

Comment: Any news about this? V2 seem impossible to use!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dialogflow Rest APIs, You need to generate access token with Google cloud sdk (scope: cloud platform, dialogflow)

```
  public df_client_call(request) {
    var config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + this.accessToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      }
    };   
   return this.http.post(
      'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/' + environment.project_id +
      '/agent/sessions/' + sessionId + ':detectIntent',
      request,
      config
    )
  }
```

In the request you have to pass,

```
{
    queryInput: {
        text: {
            text: action.payload.text,
            languageCode: 'en-US',
        },
    }
}
```

to trigger Event:,

```
    {
        queryInput: {
            event: {
                name: action.payload.event,
                languageCode: 'en-US',
            },
        }
    }
```

`sessionId` => unique Id for your user