# Dialogflow easy way for authorization

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Does exist an easy way to connect Dialogflow agent to `node.js` code? When I use this code with the correct projectID taken from the Dialogflow agent's settings page, I have the following error:

Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

```
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
```

I visited the page, but for what I want I think is quite confused (they quotes other API and a lot of setting), how can I solve this?

I want to take informations from a file and loading all without installing third party APIs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not very well documented, but the easiest way to authenticate is using the JSON file provided on your google cloud platform console.

```
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
    keyFilename: '/path/to/google.json'
});
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
```

This also works for all the other clients. `ContextsClients`, `EntityTypesClient` and so on.

Comment: thanks, it should work, but i get this error:

{ Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' on 'projects/xxxx/agent' denied.

I created for the test an access key and file correctly, with role of admin of dialogflow and owner of the project, but i still get "access denied", any ideas?

Comment: You're missing some permissions on your google cloud platform settings. It's hard to debug without access.

Comment: Do you have in `IAM` tab, your dialogflow integration added?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now i can't check out as soon as i can i will inform, thanks for your help and patience

Comment: ok you were right, it was a little distraction, now i resolved. Thanks

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande , this thing works for me...Do we have to pass the credentials the same to create Entity.  ` const entityTypesClient = new dialogflow.EntityTypesClient({'keyFilename' : './keys.json'})`  and `const intentsClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient({'keyFilename' : './keys.json'})`

Comment: @AshishsinghRawat yes, it works the same for every client. Session, intent and all the rest.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038315/upload-intent-function-dialogflow-v2 .....This is the code I have tried...Doesn't seem to work with both admin and developer privilege. Is there any syntactical error

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Might be able to skip projectID (since it's in service-account credential)-- check out this comment: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/fe8073f79e98211eb6790e9fef05dd9ea8159573/src/v2/sessions_client.ts#L64-L67

Answer (score 10):

I am writing the code, which worked for me. Please follow all the steps provided in [Reference link 2](https://medium.com/@tzahi/how-to-setup-dialogflow-v2-authentication-programmatically-with-node-js-b37fa4815d89) and for coding purpose you can use the snippet provided.

I have also added the sample JSON of Google Cloud Oauth

References:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow#samples
2. https://medium.com/@tzahi/how-to-setup-dialogflow-v2-authentication-programmatically-with-node-js-b37fa4815d89

```js
//Downloaded JSON format

{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "mybot",
  "private_key_id": "123456asd",
  "private_key": "YOURKEY",
  "client_email": "yourID@mybot.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "098091234",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/yourID%40mybot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}


//------*********************---------------------------
//
const projectId = 'mybot';

//https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents#settings
// generate session id (currently hard coded)
const sessionId = '981dbc33-7c54-5419-2cce-edf90efd2170';
const query = 'hello';
const languageCode = 'en-US';

// Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
let privateKey = 'YourKey';

// as per goolgle json
let clientEmail = "yourID@mybot.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
let config = {
  credentials: {
    private_key: privateKey,
    client_email: clientEmail
  }
}
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(config);

// Define session path
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

// The text query request.
const request = {
  session: sessionPath,
  queryInput: {
    text: {
      text: query,
      languageCode: languageCode,
    },
  },
};

// Send request and log result
sessionClient
  .detectIntent(request)
  .then(responses => {
    console.log('Detected intent');
    const result = responses[0].queryResult;
    console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
    console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
    if (result.intent) {
      console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Comment: how to run and test this ??

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue few months ago, check this, this is how i solve it. 
From your JSON that Google Cloud extract this lines.

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'
const projectId = 'projectid';
const sessionId = 'sessionId';
const query = 'text to check';


let privateKey = "private key JSON";
let clientEmail = "email acount from JSON";
let config = {
credentials: {
    private_key: privateKey,
    client_email: clientEmail
}
};

sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(config);

async function sendTextMessageToDialogFlow(textMessage, sessionId) {
// Define session path
const sessionPath = this.sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
// The text query request.
const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
        text: {
            text: textMessage,
            languageCode: LANGUAGE_CODE
        }
    }
}
try {
    let responses = await this.sessionClient.detectIntent(request)
    console.log('DialogFlow.sendTextMessageToDialogFlow: Detected intent', responses);
    return responses
} catch (err) {
    console.error('DialogFlow.sendTextMessageToDialogFlow ERROR:', err);
    throw err
}
};


sendTextMessageToDialogFlow(query, sessionId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question, the documentation for Dialogflow authentication has been improved. You should find all your answers here:

[Authentication and access contro](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/setup#authentication-and-access-control)

Answer (score 1):

I follow the above solutions with little changes :

```
// A unique identifier for the given session
const sessionId = uuid.v4();

// Create a new session

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
    keyFilename: require("path").join('config/google-credential.json')
});
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(process.env.DIALOGFLOW_PROJECTID, sessionId);
```