# set input or output context dialogflow nodejs v2

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am using `dialogflow` NPM module and I want to send `input/output context` but I am not sure how to do.
I know I can do in `google-assistant` NPM with
I can set `contexts` with `parameter` using below method,

```
 const parameters = { // Custom parameters to pass with context
     welcome: true,
 };
 conv.contexts.set('welcome-context', 5, parameters);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to send a context using the [Dialogflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) NPM module, you have to first create a context, using `dialogflow.ContextsClient` and then send it on the query.

To convert the parameters to the format required by Dialogflow you will need to use this module: [pb-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pb-util)

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
const { struct } = require('pb-util');  

const projectId = 'projectId';
const contextsClient = new dialogflow.ContextsClient();
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();

async function createContext(sessionId, contextId, parameters, lifespanCount = 5) {

    const sessionPath = contextsClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
    const contextPath = contextsClient.contextPath(
        projectId,
        sessionId,
        contextId
    );

    const request = {
        parent: sessionPath,
        context: {
            name: contextPath,
            parameters: struct.encode(parameters)
            lifespanCount
        }
    };

    const [context] = await contextsClient.createContext(request);

    return context;
}


function sendQuery(sessionId, query, context) {

    const session = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

    const request = {
        session,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                text: query
            }
        },
        queryParams: {
            contexts: [context] // You can pass multiple contexts if you wish
        }
    };

    return sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
}

(async() => {
    const parameters = { // Custom parameters to pass with context
       welcome: true
    };

    const sessionId = 'my-session';
    const context = await createContext(sessionId, 'welcome-context', parameters);

    const response = await sendQuery(sessionId, 'Hi', context);

    console.log(response);

})();
```

Have in mind that you send an input context. The output context is generated in the intent.

If you have trouble authenticating the clients `SessionClient` & `ContextClient` you can check this other question: [Dialogflow easy way for authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545943/dialogflow-easy-way-for-authorization/50546430#50546430)

Comment: Remember to add the 'languageCode' param in request.queryInput.text

Comment: Dear @Jonathan and Marcos, I  have the languageCode error but can you explain to me better where I have to put this parameter. Thank you.

Comment: the context inside the dialogflow UI looks like just a single text string, is that what we're talking about here? google sure like to complicate things, a bunch of 3rd party libs to format a string...

Comment: i get `contextsClient.sessionPath is not a function` ...

Comment: use projectAgentSessionPath & projectAgentSessionContextPath instead of sessionPath & contextPath

Answer (score 8):

First, some clarification on packages

- The [google-assistant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-assistant) package is one person's implementation/wrapper for the Assistant SDK, allowing you to embed the Assistant in any program or device. This is like building your own Google Home. (This package isn't from Google, it appears, but does wrap the official protobuf API, so you don't have to compile it yourself.)
- The [actions-on-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) package is for making a webhook that works either with the Action SDK or Dialogflow. This is for making a program that works with the Assistant and sends back responses. (ie - it is for writing the code that responds to "Hey Google, talk to my app")
- The [dialogflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) package lets you work with Dialogflow agents, including configuring them and sending queries to them to see which Intents match the queries. This is a very rough equivalent of the "google-assistant" package, but does a lot more.
- The [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-fulfillment) package is for making a webhook that provides logic and responses for any of the platforms that Dialogflow supports. It is the equivalent of the actions-on-google package.

The code fragment you provided looks like it is from the "actions-on-google" package, and is setting the output context as part of the reply.

The equivalent of your code using the "dialogflow-fulfillment" package would be

```
 const parameters = { // Custom parameters to pass with context
     welcome: true,
 };
 agent.context.set('welcome-context', 5, parameters);
```

Note that it is "context", without the "s" in this package.

Similarly, to get an input context, you would use

```
agent.context.get('name-of-context;);
```

(You may see some examples that use something like `agent.setContext()`. These methods have been deprecated in favor of the above.)

Answer (score 0):

Building on Marco's excellent answer-- here's a simpler version:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "credtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "dialogflow": "^1.2.0",
    "pb-util": "^0.1.3"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const {ContextsClient} = require('dialogflow')
const { struct } = require('pb-util');  

// REPLACE THESE:

/*
1. Service Account Credential file (KEEP SAFE)
// where/how to get this key: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys
// For different auth options, see Marco Casagrande's explainer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545943/dialogflow-easy-way-for-authorization/50546430#50546430)
// Note: JSON hard-coded below for copy/paste, just import/require in when using for real
*/

const credential = {
    "type": "__REPLACE__ME___",
    "project_id": "__REPLACE__ME___",
    "private_key_id": "__REPLACE__ME___",
    "private_key": "__REPLACE__ME___",
    "client_email": "__REPLACE__ME___",
    "client_id": "__REPLACE__ME___",
    "auth_uri": "__REPLACE__ME___",
    "token_uri": "__REPLACE__ME___",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "__REPLACE__ME___",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "__REPLACE__ME___"
  }
  
/*
2. Project ID, Google cloud project id
Tip: notice the service-account naturally already has your product id
*/
const project_id = '__REPLACE__ME___' // This is your google cloud project


const client = new ContextsClient({
    credentials: credential
});


createContext('123456789', {name: 'bongo_context', lifespanCount: 3, parameters: {a:1, b:2, c:3 }} )


function createContext(sessionID, {name, lifespanCount, parameters = {} } = {} ) {
    const formattedParent = client.sessionPath(project_id, sessionID);
    const formattedContextName = `projects/${project_id}/agent/sessions/${sessionID}/contexts/${name}`
    const context = {
        "name": formattedContextName,
        "lifespanCount": 2,
        "parameters": struct.encode(parameters)
    }

    const request = {
        parent: formattedParent,
        context: context,
    }

    client.createContext(request)
          .then(responses => {
            const response = responses[0];
            console.log('context now active:', response)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
          });

}
```

Comment: you have `thebongocontext` hardwired into the context there.