# How to handle multiple agents in Dialogflow API V2?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, sdk, dialogflow-es

I am using NodeJS SDK for accessing Dialogflow(V2) agent.I have **multiple agents** for multiple categories of business, one agent for one business.

Currently I am using single aget for my Nodejs application and I am using the nodeje SDK of V2 which requires to set an environment variable of the **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**(I mentioned private key json file path) for Authentication.

How can I implement the above functionality for **multiple agents** in my Nodejs application. 
can you please help me how to resolve this issue?

How to access listIntents method for multiple agents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multiple agents, instead of using environment variables, the best alternative is to use `keyFileName` property when creating the client.

```
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
    keyFilename: '/path/to/google.json'
});
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
```

[Dialogflow easy way for authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545943/dialogflow-easy-way-for-authorization/50546430#50546430)