# How can I handle multiple GCP service account on my Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am implementing dialogflow v2 api in my  node.js based server. 
The setup is like -  my server receives query from end user and calls dialogflow v2 api, after fetching response from dialogflow,  it sends back the response to the user.

To send request to dialogflow api, I need to set env variable named as GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS which will point to the json file of the generated service account key.

The situation is, I have multiple bots and hence multiple keys to connect with them.

In this scenario, I am thinking of changing the environment variable everyime a request arrives , according to the bot which has send the request.

My question are -
Is this the right way to handle this situation ?
What will happen if two requests arrive simultaneously , in that case will their be any issue with mix-match or collision of env variable ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would not change the environmental variable for every request. As you mentioned, the authentication is specific to a given request, whereas environmental variables should be used to store elements of configuration that are shared across all requests made to the "environment".

A common approach would be to specify the paths to service accounts individually (a dialogflow client can be initialized with a path to a service account file):

```
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
    keyFilename: '/path/to/google.json'
});
```

— code directly from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546430. Also see Google [SessionsClient docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/dialogflow/0.8.x/v2.SessionsClient#SessionsClient).

So, when a request comes in, look at some parameters of the request to determine which authentication to use, then initialize a client with the path to that authentication file. Also, goes without saying, but protect those files like passwords (don't commit them to a public repo, etc).

If you find yourself managing lots of secrets, or needing to frequently alter or update them, you might look into a service to handle this for you, like GCP's Key Management System (https://cloud.google.com/kms/) which could make key rotation / management easier to handle. [GCP blog post on service account management](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/help-keep-your-google-cloud-service-account-keys-safe).

For a small project, specifying file paths should work fine.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks for your help :)